# URL Encode in J2ME?

Tags: java, url, java-me, illegalargumentexception

I have a problem while working in a project when i'm trying to parse a String to URL so can i send my HttpRequest.The problem is that couldn't convert the String and i'm getting

**java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: no ':' in URL**

This is the method i'm using

```
 public String getResultat()  throws Exception {


     /// CODE J2ME

     int ch;
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
        HttpConnection ht;
        DataInputStream ds;
        try {

       String chx="http:x.com";

       String ecodedString=EnvoyerSMS.urlEncode(chx);

            ht = (HttpConnection) Connector.open(ecodedString);
            ds = ht.openDataInputStream();
            while ((ch = ds.read()) != -1) {
                sb.append((char)ch);
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        String reponse = sb.toString().trim();
        System.out.println("REPONSE "+reponse);
        return  reponse;
        }
```

And this is the static method that i used to convert my String

```
    public static String urlEncode(String s) {
    StringBuffer sbuf = new StringBuffer();
    int len = s.length();
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        int ch = s.charAt(i);
        if ('A' <= ch && ch <= 'Z') { // 'A'..'Z'
            sbuf.append((char)ch);
        } else if ('a' <= ch && ch <= 'z') { // 'a'..'z'
            sbuf.append((char)ch);
        } else if ('0' <= ch && ch <= '9') { // '0'..'9'
            sbuf.append((char)ch);
        } else if (ch == ' ') { // space
            sbuf.append('+');
        } else if (ch == '-' || ch == '_'   //these characters don't need encoding
                || ch == '.' || ch == '*') {
            sbuf.append((char)ch);
        } else if (ch <= 0x007f) { // other ASCII
            sbuf.append(hex(ch));
        } else if (ch <= 0x07FF) { // non-ASCII <= 0x7FF
            sbuf.append(hex(0xc0 | (ch >> 6)));
            sbuf.append(hex(0x80 | (ch & 0x3F)));
        } else { // 0x7FF < ch <= 0xFFFF
            sbuf.append(hex(0xe0 | (ch >> 12)));
            sbuf.append(hex(0x80 | ((ch >> 6) & 0x3F)));
            sbuf.append(hex(0x80 | (ch & 0x3F)));
        }
    }
    return sbuf.toString();
}

    //get the encoded value of a single symbol, each return value is 3 characters long
static String hex(int sym)
 {
     return(hex.substring(sym*3, sym*3 + 3));
 }

// Hex constants concatenated into a string, messy but efficient
final static String hex =
"%00%01%02%03%04%05%06%07%08%09%0a%0b%0c%0d%0e%0f%10%11%12%13%14%15%16%17%18%19%1a%1b%1c%1d%1e%1f" +
"%20%21%22%23%24%25%26%27%28%29%2a%2b%2c%2d%2e%2f%30%31%32%33%34%35%36%37%38%39%3a%3b%3c%3d%3e%3f" +
"%40%41%42%43%44%45%46%47%48%49%4a%4b%4c%4d%4e%4f%50%51%52%53%54%55%56%57%58%59%5a%5b%5c%5d%5e%5f" +
"%60%61%62%63%64%65%66%67%68%69%6a%6b%6c%6d%6e%6f%70%71%72%73%74%75%76%77%78%79%7a%7b%7c%7d%7e%7f" +
"%80%81%82%83%84%85%86%87%88%89%8a%8b%8c%8d%8e%8f%90%91%92%93%94%95%96%97%98%99%9a%9b%9c%9d%9e%9f" +
"%a0%a1%a2%a3%a4%a5%a6%a7%a8%a9%aa%ab%ac%ad%ae%af%b0%b1%b2%b3%b4%b5%b6%b7%b8%b9%ba%bb%bc%bd%be%bf" +
"%c0%c1%c2%c3%c4%c5%c6%c7%c8%c9%ca%cb%cc%cd%ce%cf%d0%d1%d2%d3%d4%d5%d6%d7%d8%d9%da%db%dc%dd%de%df" +
"%e0%e1%e2%e3%e4%e5%e6%e7%e8%e9%ea%eb%ec%ed%ee%ef%f0%f1%f2%f3%f4%f5%f6%f7%f8%f9%fa%fb%fc%fd%fe%ff";
}
```

Thanks :D

Comment: Don't know how important it is, but you might want to consider removing the username and password from the URL in the source code, so that it's not publicly available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

URLEncoder is not the equivalent of the code you have written. The equivalent of that is

```
new URI(null, string, null).toASCIIString()
```

Despite its name, URLEncoder isn't for encoding URLs. It is for encoding URL *arguments,* and POST key-value pairs.

Comment: I still get nothing...How can I use it exactelly please ?

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be `http://x.com` rather than `http:x.com` ?

Bu tif you have a really simple URL like that (i.e., with no parameters) you won't need to encode it at all.

However, suppose your URL does contain parameters - e.g., `http://x.com?param1=value1&param2=value2`, then you would encode just the parameter values like this:

`String encodedString = "http://x.com?param1=" + EnvoyerSMS.urlEncode(value1) + "&param2=" + EnvoyerSMS.urlEncode(value2);`

...but use a `StringBuffer` to concatenate these parts rather than using the `+` operator like I have.

NB - The reason you were getting the `no ':' in URL` error is because you had erroneously encoded the entire URL, so the `:` character was also encoded (into whatever its encoded equivalent is).

If you do `System.out.println(encodedString);` you will see what URL your `HttpConnection` object is trying to work with.